# Splunk to Elasticsearch datamodel translation

Tags: elasticsearch, splunk, datamodel

I'm trying to convert Splunk searches to Elasticsearch searches. The one problem I'm having is what to do with Splunk's datamodels. How would I transfer performing the search in a specific datamodel in Splunk to an Elasticsearch search?

For example, in a Splunk search:
tstats summariesonly=T count from datamodel="Web"........

What would be the Elasticsearch equivalent to performing the search in the "Web" datamodel?

Any help, no matter how small will help indeed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Open the query in search and use the search inspector. The inspector will show you know which query splunk has actually executed.

While `tstats` searches index-time fields, you will have to reproduce all datamodel fields and aggregations (i.e. datamodel acceleration) and this is not an easy task, if at all possible.